# Python alternative to global variable

Tags: python, function, variables, global

I have a python project in which I have a function `test_function`. Inside test_function I have a variable `a`, but I want to use it inside another function called `test_function2`. I do not want to make `a` a global variable. Is there any other way?

```
def test_function():
    a = "hello"


def test_function2():
    if a == "hello":
        print(a)
    else:
        print("hello world")
```

Comment: I think this is the classic example where global state is necessary. If you _aren't_ calling `test_function` inside `test_function2` but still want to check for some status of `test_function`, you'll need a global variable (or put the functions in a class and make `a` the class' attribute).

Comment: have it as an argument/return the new value

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just call `test_function2(a)` inside `test_function()` directly and pass the variable?

Comment: Thank you for responding so fast , could you give me an example of "a" being a class atribute.I am really new to programming and I don't understand classes verry well.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> **Python return statement**
>
> The return statement is used to return from a function i.e. break out
>   of the function. We can optionally return a value from the function as
>   well.

```
def test_function():
    a = "hello"
    return a # returns variable a


def test_function2():
    a = test_function()
    if a == "hello":
        print(a)
    else:
        print("hello world")

test_function2()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below. Take a function as argument and call it with `a` as argument. Now you can pass any function that needs a as input without exposing `a` outside the `test_function`.

```
def test_function(func = lambda a : None):
    a = "hello"
    func(a)


def test_function2(a):
    if a == "hello":
        print(a)
    else:
        print("hello world")

test_function(test_function2)
```